# Trying to count the duplicate entries in a table using PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am using the following query:

```
SELECT Print_NUMBER, 
       COUNT(Print_NUMBER) TotalCount
  FROM LS_Print_Queue
  WHERE event_id = 11862
  GROUP BY PRINT_NUMBER
  HAVING COUNT(PRINT_NUMBER) > 1 
  ORDER BY COUNT(PRINT_NUMBER) DESC
```

and it returns a table of print numbers which are duplicates and the count of how many duplicates for that particular print number. What I want to do is summarize that data and just provide a total amount of duplicates. So if I had 26 rows with 2 duplicates per row it would return 52 or if one of those duplicate rows had three duplicates it would return 53. How do I accomplish this in Oracle PL/SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can readily do it with a subquery:

```
select sum(TotalCount)
from (SELECT Print_NUMBER, COUNT(Print_NUMBER) as TotalCount
      FROM LS_Print_Queue
      WHERE event_id = 11862
      GROUP BY PRINT_NUMBER
      HAVING COUNT(PRINT_NUMBER) > 1 
     ) t
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried that several times before posting. You are right it should work but it was not working within the Application Express SQL Workshop provided by Oracle. However, bolstered by your advice I created a page within the application and ran the query and voila it worked.

The problem was not my logic but my tool!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using analytic functions you can get the pk/rowid for the rows that are duplicated

http://technology.amis.nl/2011/08/02/remove-duplicate-rows-with-oracle-sql-row_number-intelligent-and-efficient-data-cleansing/